# getExternalFilesDir() returns null

Tags: android

One of my app's users has reported an error in my app, where `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` returns null.

I have added `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission as following.

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

I have used `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` because android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) says that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is not necessary to write to directory returned by `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`, starting from Android 4.4 (sdk 19).

But, if I remove `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` from the permission, `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` returns a non null value.

The device this happens is Oppo Find 7 with Android 4.4.2 ([SDK version 19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.4.E2.80.934.4.4_KitKat_.28API_level_19.29)).

Can someone explain why this happens? What should I do to fix this? Removing `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` fixes the problem, but as per the documentation, the permission is unnecessary in later android versions.

Comment: When you are getting external files this means you are reading files from external storage so instead of write you need read permission for this

Comment: @VivekMishra, My app is working fine in all devices I tested without READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. So you mean it is working due to a coincidence?

Comment: @VivekMishra: There is no need for permissions starting with KitKat and newer versions of android. Quoting official documentation: "Starting in KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling application. To access paths belonging to other packages, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required."

Comment: @Simon-Droid it is not described anywhere in question whether it is from returned path or other packages, so I think my concern is correct